# MySql status order by

Tags: mysql

I have a query in messages table and i want them to be sorted by the status of the message. Those that have status like 'unread' and the recent ones must comes first. 
How should i do the order by clause in which those unread will be on top as well as among those unread, those that comes last will be on top?

This is my code

```
   select message_id,sender,penname,dp,message,TIMEDIFF(now(),date_sent) as date,status
   from message_log,user 
   where recepient = 11 and sender = user_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `order by` clause:

```
select message_id,sender,penname,dp,message,TIMEDIFF(now(),date_sent) as date,status
from message_log,user 
where recepient = 11 and sender = user_id
order by status = 'unread' desc,
      date_sent desc;
```

This puts all the "unread" ones at the top, in date descending order.  Then the rest of the messages.